# Android SQLite Database: Syntax error when adding to database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, syntax-error

Hi I'm getting this error when adding data to my database but i can't figure out why. I think the problem is in the addData()-Method, but none of my atempts to fix it have worked so far.

"E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "Aktivität": syntax error"

as well as:

"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Aktivität": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MedDatenTabelle(Schmerz,Broteinheiten,Messzeit,Wasser,Diastole,Müdigkeit,Puls,Symptom,letzte Aktivität,Gewicht,Kalorien,Bemerkungen,Systole,Temperatur,Blutzucker) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "MedDatenManager";

    private static final String TABLE_MEDDATEN = "MedDatenTabelle";


    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_SYST = "Systole";
    private static final String KEY_DIAST = "Diastole";
    private static final String KEY_PULS = "Puls";
    private static final String KEY_BLUTZ = "Blutzucker";
    private static final String KEY_TEMP = "Temperatur";
    private static final String KEY_GEW = "Gewicht";
    private static final String KEY_KAL = "Kalorien";
    private static final String KEY_BE ="Broteinheiten";
    private static final String KEY_WASSER = "Wasser";
    private static final String KEY_TIME = "Messzeit";
    private static final String KEY_SCHMERZ = "Schmerz";
    private static final String KEY_MUD = "Müdigkeit";
    private static final String KEY_AKTI = "letzte Aktivität";
    private static final String KEY_SYMP = "Symptom";
    private static final String KEY_BEM = "Bemerkungen";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String CREATE_TABLE_MEDDATEN = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEDDATEN + " ("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_SYST + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DIAST + " TEXT," + KEY_PULS + " TEXT," + KEY_BLUTZ + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TEMP + " TEXT," + KEY_GEW + " TEXT," + KEY_KAL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BE + " TEXT," + KEY_WASSER + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_SCHMERZ + " TEXT," + KEY_MUD + " TEXT," + KEY_AKTI + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_SYMP + " TEXT," + KEY_BEM + " TEXT" + " )";
        database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MEDDATEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEDDATEN);

        onCreate(database);
    }

    public void addData (MEDDATEN meddaten){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_SCHMERZ,meddaten.getSchmerz());
        values.put(KEY_BE,meddaten.getBroteinheiten());
        values.put(KEY_TIME,meddaten.getMesszeit());
        values.put(KEY_WASSER,meddaten.getWasser());
        values.put(KEY_MUD,meddaten.getMüdigkeit());
        values.put(KEY_DIAST,meddaten.getDiastole());
        values.put(KEY_PULS,meddaten.getPuls());
        values.put(KEY_SYMP,meddaten.getSymptome());
        values.put(KEY_AKTI,meddaten.getLetzteAkt());
        values.put(KEY_GEW,meddaten.getGewicht());
        values.put(KEY_KAL,meddaten.getKalorien());
        values.put(KEY_BEM,meddaten.getBemerkungen());
        values.put(KEY_TEMP,meddaten.getTemperatur());
        values.put(KEY_SYST,meddaten.getSystole());
        values.put(KEY_BLUTZ,meddaten.getBlutzucker());

        database.insert(TABLE_MEDDATEN, null, values);
        database.close();

        }




    }


}
```

Comment: Post your entire logcat and the method calling addData.

Comment: change column name KEY_AKTI = "letzte_Aktivität" instead of "letzte Aktivität".

Comment: @JaiRajesh Curiously, that's exactly what I wrote in my answer, 3 minutes before your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is here (the **space** in the field name, without qualifiers):

```
private static final String KEY_AKTI = "letzte Aktivität"
```

try

```
private static final String KEY_AKTI = "letzte_Aktivität"
```

instead.

---

If the space is **mandatory**, try:

```
private static final String KEY_AKTI = "'letzte Aktivität'"
```

Or

```
private static final String KEY_AKTI = "[letzte Aktivität]"
```

Or

```
private static final String KEY_AKTI = "`letzte Aktivität`"
```

---

Reference: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html